# Get iPhone contacts into Gmail

Tags: ios, gmail

I have an Android phone and imported all my contacts from Gmail. Most of my old contacts weren't in Gmail, but on the iPhone 3GS.  Now getting the iPhone contacts into Gmail is proving to be a huge pain, there is a ton of information about this on the web but a lot of it must be outdated and none of the methods have worked for me yet.

How can I get contacts of iOS 5 iphone 3GS, and into Gmail so that they can be visible on my new Android phone (Galaxy Nexus)?

I've been trying for 4 hours and it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the [IDrive](http://www.idrive.com/idrive-lite/) app on your iphone and your android. Contacts transfered within seconds. Then sync with gmail.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!   It worked easily, and I didn't even need to open the dreaded iTunes (worst piece of software ever written???)

Answer (score 0):

I use SyncInABlink. http://www.syncinablink.com/SyncInABlink.aspx

It costs $5 but it's worth it if you don't want to use more time.